# "Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

i am getting error in 1st line

```
Dim result = (CInt(Split(Overtime.Text, ":")(0)) * 60 + CInt(Split(Overtime.Text, ":")(1)))
OvertimeAmount.Text = (result * Val(OvertimeRate.Text)) / 60
```

Comment: Did you debug the code ?
Whats the Overtime.Text value in the Quickwatch ?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Why do you do the split twice? Think about expanding the code to multiple steps and check each step at a time. You are doing too much at the same time without understanding what is going on.

Comment: @Istern Overtime.text contains total overtime of employee between two selected date

Comment: @JulesMazur “Conversion from string ”" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim i As Integer
Integer.TryParse(value, i)
Console.WriteLine("Integer:", i)
```

Comment: its not working, still getting the same error in 1st line in my above given code

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string containing a numeric value to an actual numerical type (eg int) you need to use

```
Integer.Parse(someString)
```

Comment: i am still getting the same error..nothing is working for me..please help

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this will work:

```
Dim Result as Integer = TimeSpan.Parse(Overtime.Text).TotalMinutes
OvertimeAmount.Text = ((result * Val(OvertimeRate.Text)) / 60).ToString
```

This assumes you are validating the text in Overtime.  If not you can use the TryParse method.

```
    Dim ts As New TimeSpan
    Dim ValidText As Boolean = TimeSpan.TryParse(Overtime.Text, ts)
    If ValidText Then
        Dim Result as Integer = ts.TotalMinutes
    End If
```